# What does jQuery use to minify their css and javascript?

Tags: jquery, minify

I know that they use Google Closure for their Js files in 1.4 but what about css?

Comment: Just in case you don't know about it, I use this online version of google closure compiler: http://closureoptimizer.com/

Answer (score 6):

jQuery doesn't have any CSS:)

jQuery UI [doesn't minify their CSS](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) :)

That being said, I use the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) to minify CSS in projects as a build step and it's worked very well, CSS minification isn't that complicated, so it's hard to go wrong here.

Comment: @Marko - I don't recall them doing this, maybe they did at some point, but not in the past year or two, that I've ever come across anyway.

Comment: Good answer, what about the JS though?

Comment: @Marko - That part's in the question :) The [closure compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) ...we're also using that in the build to compress JS as a pre-build step on the web project, if you're completely outside the pages you'll get a ton of additional compression out of the advanced optimizations.

Comment: @Nick, well, CSS minification can be complicated when it gets a little farther than spaces and comments removal... like rules optimisation. ;)

Comment: @Julian - I don't see how any minifier could do that though, since it would require every scenario of markup that goes with it.  I do agree you can *optimize* CSS better, but that's not the same as minification.

Comment: @Nick: http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/ for instance optimizes expressions within a given rule. I saw others that would also unite similar rules to avoid repetition. You'd be surprised. Though most of those solutions fail when confronted to production code with non-standard stuff ;)